# Algolia vue instant search: Stack search results from searchStore

Tags: vue.js, algolia, vue-instant-search

In [this](https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/ZoMpaM?editors=1010) example, Algolia increases the page number and stacks results on top of each other:

```
<ais-results :stack="true">
```

This means that during this method:

```
methods: {
  loadMore: function() {
    this.page++;
  }
}
```

All the results load on top of each other.

I'd like to recreate this, but I'm using a custom component:

```
import { Component } from "vue-instantsearch"; 

export default {
  components: { "v-image": VImage },
  mixins: [Component],
  computed: {
    results() {
      return this.searchStore.results;
    },
    rows() {
      var arr = this.results;
      var len = 3;
      var chunks = [],
        i = 0,
        n = arr.length;
      while (i < n) {
        chunks.push(arr.slice(i, (i += len)));
      }
      return chunks;
    }
  }
};
```

Is there any way I can set the `:stack="true"` on my [search store](https://community.algolia.com/vue-instantsearch/getting-started/search-store.html)? I have been looking for a method to apply to the `return this.searchStore.results;`

Comment: stack is implemented like this: https://github.com/algolia/vue-instantsearch/blob/master/src/components/Results.vue#L50-L79